# How do I handle a user using zoom +/- and still maintain responsiveness in my HTML

Tags: html, css, zooming

My issue is that the markup works great and is responsive, but if the user uses the zoom feature in chrome or edge -/+ the image is not responsive it stays exactly the same size. Note: my image is rendered as a background.

```css
-- CSS
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .hero-banner {
        height: 684px;
        overflow: hidden
    }
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 320px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 230px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: none
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"]>.container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1128px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .copy {
    max-width: 493px
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] h2 {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--scent-color)
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .links p {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .btn-link {
    color: var(--scent-color)
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .image {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -381.33px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 381.33px;
    margin-top: -50px
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] {
        background-size: 100% auto
    }

    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .image {
        top: -340px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] {
        height: 684px;
        padding: 0;
        background-size: auto 551px;
        background-position: center bottom 133px;
        font-size: 20px
    }

    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"]>.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 549px
    }

    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] h2 {
        font-size: 18px
    }

    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] h1 {
        font-size: 54px
    }

    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .image {
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        max-height: 1200px;
        width: 1300px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        margin: 0
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    .hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] {
        background-size: 100% auto
    }
}

body:not(.no-js) .hero-banner .hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd {
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-image: url(../img/home/bg_microban_overlay1.png), url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_bkgrnd.png);
    background-size: 96%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 40%, center
}

body:not(.no-js) .hero-banner .hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd3 {
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-image: url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_bkgrnd3_a.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center
}

body:not(.no-js) .hero-banner .hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd2 {
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/3r4m51TR/bg-microban-overlay2.png), url(https://i.postimg.cc/Twn7t6C8/bg-hero-microban-bkgrnd.png);
    background-size: 96%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left, center
}

.hero-banner [class^="hero-scent_"] .btn-link:hover {
    color: #00235b
}

.hero-banner .tns-nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .hero-banner .tns-nav {
        margin-top: -100px
    }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<div class="hero-banner">
      <div class="hero-slider">
        <div class="hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd2"></div>
        <div class="hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd3"></div>                
        <div class="hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd"></div>               
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I added a sample. Run snippet in full screen, then use the zoom controls on your browser. You should notice that the image cuts off. this is not the case if you increase or decrease the window size

Comment: There's a lot of CSS in your example that isn't being used. Part of creating a minimal example is removing all of the excess